# Swift UITextView HTML Image causes crash when copying

Tags: html, swift, image, uitextview, copy-paste

I currently have a UITextView that would represent an article in the app that I'm making. From the database, I am pulling a simple string that contains HTML formatting that I parse on-device. This is the function that parses the HTML for reference.

```swift
let htmlData = NSString(string: s).data(using: String.Encoding.unicode.rawValue);
    let options = [NSAttributedString.DocumentReadingOptionKey.documentType:
        NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html];
    do{
        let t = try NSMutableAttributedString(data: htmlData ?? Data(), options: options, documentAttributes: nil);
        t.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.font, value: UIFont(name: "SFProDisplay-Regular", size: CGFloat(fontSize)) as Any, range: NSMakeRange(0, t.length));
        return t;
    }
    catch let error{
        print(error);
        return NSMutableAttributedString(string: s);
    }
```

Anyways, in the article, this is the html code that is causing the issue:

```html
Thanks!&nbsp;<span class="q9uorilb tbxw36s4 knj5qynh kvgmc6g5 ditlmg2l oygrvhab nvdbi5me fgm26odu gl3lb2sf hhz5lgdu"><img src="https://static.xx.fbcdn.net/images/emoji.php/v9/tfb/1/16/263a.png" alt="☺️" width="16" height="16" /></span></p>
```

On the app, it currently looks like this:

[image: image in text]

When long pressed, it opens up this menu on ios:
[image: menu options]

When pressing on the copy image button, it throws this error in xcode:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[_UIConcretePasteboard setImage:]: Argument is not an object of type UIImage [(null)]'
```

I've looked online for a solution but it seems like there hasn't been anyone else with this issue. I've only seen solutions for people who have had issues pasting to the uitextview. I would think that converting the image into a UIImage would help fix this issue but I have no clue on where to start with an html image. Anything that will point me in the right direction will be greatly appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: I have the same issue, any ideas guys?

Comment: any luck with this? having same issue but no luck finding a solution.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65635974/swift-uitextview-html-image-causes-crash-when-copy-image-is-selected-after-long/65641586 is the same question