# swift uitextview html image causes crash when copy image is selected after long press

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, uitextview, copy-paste

I currently have a UITextView that is displaying an NSAttributedString that contains HTML data with text and images. This data is received via API so images and text are all combined into one HTML string. This is the function that parses the HTML.

```
let htmlData = NSString(string: myString).data(using: String.Encoding.unicode.rawValue);
let options = [NSAttributedString.DocumentReadingOptionKey.documentType:
    NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html];
do{
    let text = try NSMutableAttributedString(data: htmlData ?? Data(), options: options, documentAttributes: nil);
    text.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.font, value: UIFont(name: "Arial", size: CGFloat(fontSize)) as Any, range: NSMakeRange(0, text.length));
    return text;
}
catch let error{
    print(error);
    return NSMutableAttributedString(string: myString);
}
```

When long pressing on the image, a menu appears with two options (1. Copy image 2. Save to Camera Roll). When I click on Copy image, the app crashes with this error message:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[_UIConcretePasteboard setImage:]: Argument is not an object of type UIImage [(null)]'
```

Does anyone know how to fix this so when long pressing on the image and selecting Copy image, it will not crash?

Comment: Same question as this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63331409/swift-uitextview-html-image-causes-crash-when-copying

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert images from html to NSTextAttachment, like you do it for text to NSAttributedString. And when attach these attachments to NSAttributedString.

It can look somehow like this:

```swift
let htmlData = NSString(string: myString).data(using: String.Encoding.unicode.rawValue)
let options = [NSAttributedString.DocumentReadingOptionKey.documentType:
    NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html]
let image = UIImage(named: IMAGENAME_FROM_HTML) ?? UIImage()
let imageAttachment = NSTextAttachment(image: image)

do {
    let text = try NSMutableAttributedString(data: htmlData ?? Data(), options: options, documentAttributes: nil)
    text.addAttribute(.font, value: UIFont(name: "Arial", size: CGFloat(fontSize), range: NSMakeRange(0, text.length))
    let textWithAttachment = try NSAttributedString(attachment: imageAttachment)
    text.replaceCharacters(in: NSMakeRange(RANGE_FOR_IMAGE_IN_HTML), with: textWithAttachment)
    return text
}
catch let error {
    print(error)
    return NSMutableAttributedString(string: myString)
}
```

P.S. don't use semicolon on the lines end in swift.

Comment: That makes sense and I read about using your approach prior to posting, but the issue of implementing this is actually getting the image. There could be multiple images and they are embedded in the html. The images don't have names. The images begin with src=data:image/png;base64. I don't want to use a third party tool for parsing.

Comment: if it always will be in this format - when it's simple regexp to get all the images data. you can't do it another way if want to support images saving.

Comment: Will you clarify what you mean.

Comment: you have some html code where images presented as <image src=data:image/png;base64/> or something like this. it's very easy to get all images datas and it's Ranges (for attaches placement) without any third party libs with some regexp or any different approach to work with text - it's not rocket science at all. and make attaches from this data. And you don't have any other options if you want to support images saving.

Comment: Ok. I got it! Thank you. I will give it a try.